# Extend return value of class instance method

Tags: ruby, class, instance-methods

I have a class that have an instance method, that returns a hash. I can't change the code of that class directly, but I can extend it with modules. I need to add some new keys to the returning hash of the method. Something like this:

```ruby
class Processor
  def process
    { a: 1 }
  end
end

module ProcessorCustom
  def process
    super.merge(b: 2) # Not works :(
  end
end

Processor.send :include, ProcessorCustom

processor = Processor.new
processor.process  # returns { a: 1 }, not { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `include` is public since Ruby 2.1, so there's no need to use `send` any more (unless you are working with legacy code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-prepend) instead of `include`:

```
Processor.prepend(ProcessorCustom)

processor = Processor.new
processor.process
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

`prepend` and `include` result in different ancestor order:

```
module A; end
module B; end
module C; end

B.ancestors     #=> [B]

B.include(C)
B.ancestors     #=> [B, C]

B.prepend(A)
B.ancestors     #=> [A, B, C]
```

#### Alternatives

Depending on your use-case, you could also [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) a specific instance: (this doesn't affect other instances)

```
processor = Processor.new
processor.extend(ProcessorCustom)
processor.process
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Or use [`SimpleDelegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) to implement a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
require 'delegate'
class ProcessorCustom < SimpleDelegator
  def process
    super.merge(b: 2)
  end
end

processor = ProcessorCustom.new(Processor.new)
processor.process  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Comment: Good answer. One note:  `prepend` working only in Ruby >= 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I think the first option to consider would be the one requiring the least work by the reader to comprehend; and in Object Oriented software that would be a subclass to specialize the behavior of the superclass. I would deviate from this if, and only if, there were a compelling reason to do so.

How about this?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Processor
  def foo
    { x: 3 }
  end
end


class MyProcessor < Processor
  def foo
    super.merge({ y: 7 })
  end
end

p MyProcessor.new.foo  # outputs: {:x=>3, :y=>7}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create a proxy than to pollute the original class.

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end

  # add some syntactic sugar
  singleton_class.class_eval { alias [] new }

  def process
    @target.process.merge!(b: 2)
  end
end

Proxy[Processor.new].process  #=> {a: 1, b: 2}
```

You can even create your own dynamic proxy.

```
class DynamicProxy < BasicObject
  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end

  # again, add some syntactic sugar
  singleton_class.class_eval { alias [] new }

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    super unless @target.respond_to?(name)
    # Do something before calling the target method
    result = @target.send(name, *args, &block)
    # Do something after calling the target method
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_private = false)
    @target.respond_to?(name, include_private)
  end
end
```

To hide the detail of creating `Processor` instance, you can make a simple factory to handle the creation.

```
module ProcessorFactory
  def self.create
    DynamicProxy[Processor.new]
  end
end
```

Then you can do your job

```
ProcessorFactory.create.process
```